# Javascript .sort() function: what are return 0, return -1 and return 1 for?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am studying Javascript and currently learning the .sort() function for arrays. I understood that it can take either no argument or one between a-b and b-a.

What I don't understand however is the use of `return 0`, `return -1` and `return 1`. Here is an example (source: http://www.codewars.com/kata/572df796914b5ba27c000c90) :

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,100,999]
arr.sort((a,b)=>{
  if (a%2==b%2) return a-b;
  if (a%2>b%2) return -1;
  return 1;
})
console.log(arr)

//output: [ 1, 3, 5, 999, 2, 4, 6, 100 ]
```

I understand what it's supposed to do, i.e. separate odd and even numbers and sort them in ascending order. But what is the meaning of `return -1` and `return 1`? Can someone walk me through this function step by step?

I tried to play with the code and change some values, for example change `return -1` to `return 0`, to try to understand how it could work, but I still don't get it.

Where can I find resources with details about that `return` element?

Comment: Read the doc. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort

Comment: 3 possible outcomes of a sort comparison. Less than, greater than and equal to.

Comment: They are not `-1` and `+1`. They are negative, zero or positive values. It doesn't have to be `-1`, any negative value does the job.

Answer (score 5):

According to the **[sort docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**:

> If the parameter functionComparison is supplied, the elements of the
>   array are sorted according to the return value of the comparison
>   function. If a and bare two elements to compare, then:
>
> If `functionComparison(a, b)` is less than `0`, we sort a with an index
>   less than `b`( `a` will be ranked before `b`)
>
> If `functionComparison(a, b)` `returns 0`, we leave `a` and `b` unchanged
>   relative to each other, but sorted with respect to all the other
>   elements. Note: The ECMAScript standard does not guarantee this
>   behavior, so all browsers (eg Mozilla versions prior to 2003) do not
>   respect this. If `functionComparison(a, b)` is greater than `0`, we sort `b`
>   with an index less than `a`.
>
> `functionComparison(a, b)` must always return the same result from the
>   same pair of arguments. If the function returns inconsistent results,
>   then the order in which the items are sorted is not defined.

Now if `a > b`, `returning 1` or `a positive value` is one and the same thing, similarly, if `a < b` then returning `-1` or the `difference` is the same. If `both are equal` the `difference is 0` and hence `return 0`

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I find resources with details about that return element?

`return` value is for the *`comparator`* function.
As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort)

> If `comparefn` is not `undefined`, it should be a function that accepts
>   two arguments x and y and returns a **negative** value if x < y, **zero** if x
>   = y, or a **positive** value if x > y.

Answer (score 0):

First a general comment.  The design of using 0, negative, or positive to move stuff around in the list is so you can sort numbers from smallest to largest by doing:

arr.sort((a,b)=> { return a-b })

I'll break it down line-by-line:

Your input data...

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,100,999]
```

No comment

```
arr.sort((a,b)=>{
```

% is a remainder, a%2 is 0 if a is even and 1 if it's odd.  So to run this return the numbers are either both even or both odd.  This line sorts the even numbers within their group and the odd within theirs.

```
  if (a%2==b%2) return a-b;
```

The only way for a%2 to be greater than b%2 is for a to be odd (a%2==1) and b even (b%2==0).  This pushes the odd numbers to the start of the list.

```
  if (a%2>b%2) return -1;
```

If it makes it here, the only case left with a%2 and b%2 is a%2<b%2.  a is even and b is odd, so this has even numbers bubble up to the other end of the list.

```
  return 1;
})
```

Print the results

```
console.log(arr)

//output: [ 1, 3, 5, 999, 2, 4, 6, 100 ]
```

As a side note, if you return 0, the values are considered equal.  If you are sorting numbers, the numbers ARE equal; if you're sorting a table by a few columns and happen to have a "tie", the javascript engine can sort them as it sees fit.